# WSO 2 EI Response change the first letter to uppercase

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Hi in wso2 ei in payload factory i am getting the response in json

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
<format>{
"Body":$1
}
</format>
<args>
<arg evaluator="json" expression="$."/>
</args>
```

And the Response is :

```
{
"Body":{
   "result":"done",
   "idNumber":"123",
   "address":{
      "local":"US",
      "abroad":"UK" 
    }
}
}
```

.... means multiple objects now what i need that all object first letter should be uppercase.

I need the below response

```
 {
    "Body":{
       "Result":"done",
       "IdNumber":"123",
       "Address":{
          "local":"US",
          "abroad":"UK" 
        }
    }
 }
```

Means only the object first letter should be capitalize...Any help!

Comment: @amg_amit Can you please help me in this.

Comment: Sure @Chris Ryan , however before calling payload mediator how are you getting the argument $1, if you can try changing there then it should be easy, if you are unable to do so that we need to look into xslt mediator as payload mediator is not powerful enough for this.

Comment: @amg_amit thanks for your reply. well before payload is my wsdl endpoint in In Sequence which is giving me XML soap response and after that this is the payload and this payload is converting this into Json and display all data.

Comment: Who has created the wsdl is that your's or clients, if it is yours you can change the xsd which is being referred in wsdl, if it is client's then only option is to use xslt mediator over payload mediator, can you give me the same response after wsdl so that i can try framing xslt

Comment: This is the response half part i am getting from client wsdl

<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="xxx">
        <abc:pid xmlns:abc="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <abc:number>233232</abc:number>
            <abc:idnmbr>
                <abc:number>234234</abc:number>
                <abc:issue>2015-12-06</abc:issue>
                <abc:expiry>2018-11-28</abc:expiry>
            </abc:idnmbr>
            <abc:nat>
                <abc:id>1</abc:id>
   </abc:nat>

Comment: @amg_amit now payload not giving me this abc: but i need that after this abc: anything like pid, number ,issue etc etc first letter should be capital.

Comment: Please find my answer, try removing payload and replace it with xslt mediator

Answer (score 0):

Replace payload mediator with xslt mediator .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" media-type="application/json" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
        {
        Body :{

        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='pid']">

            Result:<xsl:value-of select="result"/>
            IdNumber:<xsl:value-of select="idNumber"/>

        </xsl:for-each>

        }

        }

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Once this is done then you need to use property mediator so that the payload is still in json.

```
 <property name="messageType" scope="default" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="contentType" scope="default" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

Comment: The response is dynamic where the object can be less or more i can't  hardcore the object keys.